# How to save current state of html body php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a html website with Sortable.js. I want to save the current state of the body when a user rearranges the list and clicks a save button. I don’t want it to save to local storage but directly to the hosted file, replacing the body html with the new rearranged version.

```html
<body>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <ul class='list'>
      <li class='item' contenteditable='true'>Item 1</li>
      <li class='item' contenteditable='true'>Item 2</li>
      <li class='item' contenteditable='true'>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
    <button class='add-item'>add new item</button>
    <button class='save'>save changes</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

I believe what I’m trying to achieve is very simple and can be done using php and ajax, but I can’t find any direct answer to my question.

Currently there is only one index.php file.

Security is no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to something like this...

```
   <body>
      <div class='wrapper'>
        <ul class='list'>
          <li class='item' contenteditable='true'>Item 1</li>
          <li class='item' contenteditable='true'>Item 2</li>
          <li class='item' contenteditable='true'>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
        <button class='add-item'>add new item</button>
        <button class='save' onclick="saveHTML()">save changes</button>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Java script

```
function saveHTML(){
  var currentStateHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
  console.log(currentStateHTML);//For debugging
  $.post("file.php", {type : "save", state : currentStateHTML},
     function(data, status){
        if(status == "success"){
          if(data == "saved"){
            location.reload();//which is index.php itself
          }
          else console.log("error");
        }
     }
  );
}
```

php file

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['type'])){
     if($_POST['type'] == "save"){
        $html = $_POST['state'];
        if(file_put_contents("index.php", $html)){
           echo "saved";
           //The file got updated
        } 
        else "error";
     }
  }
?>
```

**Note:-** Updating/Erasing/Appending to a file in your case html/php file is a complex and sensitive task, you can explore more on this, the above code is just an example and might be inappropriate.

**Suggestions:-**

1. Do not try to update file containing `php` script, why.? because `document.documentElement.innerHTML;` will only get you the `frontend` of your page, which is risky while updating the actual backend file.
2. Save all/updatable/editable file {containing only front end view} in a separate folder, and do changes accordingly, and when saved/changed/reloaded include these files into your page.
3. Try to keep the front end and back end scripts as separately as possible.

For any queries comment down.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I only changed 'document.documentElement.innerHTML;' to 'document.querySelector("html").outerHTML;'. because it was adding some styles and loom-containers from my loom extension.